# \n\n\ to break lines in unicode

Tags: unicode

I'm using unicode to parse from pyton ,and I'm using \n\n\ to break lines

the parsing is working ok,as I see that the result is with correct breaks lines,

but still in the final html I get the is no line breaking

Comment: Can you add some screenshot for better understanding?

Comment: Because line breaks mean nothing in HTML...? Only `<br>` does...?

Comment: Are the line breaks missing in the HTML file itself, or in the visual presentation (e.g. in a browser)?

Comment: in the visual presentation (e.g. in a browser). is there a script that will recognize the the line breaks on unicode and will convert them to br's?

Comment: @deceze Well that's just false :P, it's just that the default `white-space: normal;` renders new lines as spaces, and then collapses them. But they remain fully in the DOM and the superficial rendering can be changed at any time

Answer (score 0):

To create a line break in HTML , use the `<br>` tag.